# Curl JSONRPC to localhost:8545

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I am trying to do a simple curl from the cmd line to my private blockchain.
I have the geth console running on `localhost:8545`

The curl command I am executing is the following

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' http://localhost:8545
```

I also have tried many other examples from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

none of them work on my set up as all the responses are

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}}}
```

I start geth using this:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal" --datadir c:\privatechain
```

Answer (score 8):

windows needs the content in double quotes and those inside with \"

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"net_version\",\"params\":[],\"id\":67}" http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add address,as follows: `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:8545`

Comment: Thank you. I did have  that already.. I forgot to state that in my OP...

Even with that I still get the error unfortunately

Comment: At first, you must be start testrc service on single terminal, and then execute JSON RPC op. If you have get error, please tell me error log.

Comment: the other way, start geth on single terminal:  `geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545` , and then execute JSON RPC op.

Comment: I edit the original post to include the http://localhost:8545 to the command. Using Parity I had to add -H "Content-Type: application/json", but it totally worked. I've seen this once or twice because the quotes were 'enhanced' quotes from autocorrect in my text editor. Type the command in full from command line as opposed to copy and paste (if you're copying and pasting).

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error after typing it manually.
Its driving me nuts....

Here is a screen shot

https://ibb.co/b5mBEk

Comment: I also added -H "Content-Type: application/json" as suggested but I am still in the same boat

Comment: I just ran curl in verbose mode and it says connection refused.

Perhaps a firewall issue?  Will check

Comment: I ran it again using 127.0.0.1:8545, this time per curl verbose mode it connected... however I am still gettiing the same -32600 error

https://ibb.co/jkX40Q

Comment: I'm no longer a Microsoft software user, but this may have to do with your quotation marks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter also, I don't see the http content being posted from your `curl` client. Not sure if that's related.

Comment: fell no love again, HaHaHa. it's a quotation problem. For JSON RPC,you can download [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your requests. Here is a screen shot [https://ibb.co/c9jnLQ](https://ibb.co/c9jnLQ)

Comment: Nothing but love for you here man!

Well Postman is pretty sweet. Thank you for putting me on to that... 

The request goes smoothly in Postman as it should.

However, I still cant figure out why it doesn't like the command using curl on the command prompt..

On the curl command I tried every combination of quotes including reversing the ' for " and vice versa and manually typed it all out but still nothing...


https://ibb.co/eKdnpv

Answer (score 0):

i try this and it work

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"net_version\",\"params\":[],\"id\":67}' localhost:8545
```

i'm using terminal powershell in windows